# Magento2.2.3 attribute options sort order

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2.3

I am having an issue in our Magento 2.2.3 based website. I changed the order of the attribute options in the admin panel. Reindex, recompiled and still the options on front end are not matching the order I have in the admin panel.

For example I have an attribute named "color" with the below options that are in the below order in admin panel:
  yellow  |  orange  |  red  |  blue  | black

In the front end I see the order as
orange |  blue   |  yellow  | black  | red

i have read there was a known buy in magento 2.0, and 2.1 but nothing about if its still a bug or more importantly how to fix it in v2.2.3 
suggestions?

Comment: can you check link : https://www.mag-manager.com/product-information/magento-product-management/change-sort-order-of-attribute-dropdowns-and-options-in-magento-2/

Comment: thank you but I have already logged into the magento admin panel and went to the attribute and dragged/dropped the individual options into the order i wanted them. However my issue is the options are still not showing in order.

Comment: It is displayed as when you first time save it. After that, it is not sorting in Magento 2. You can fulfill your requirement by adding some script.